# MSnakes using opencv 3.1

Tags: python, opencv

I found Msnakes at [here](https://github.com/marciojmo/MSnakes).
Python 3.4.3, Numpy 1.11 (numpy==1.11), OpenCV 3.1.0 (opencv-python==3.1.0)

There is an error at main.py:

```
# Creates the snake
snake = snake.Snake( image, closed = True )
```

The error as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-71f52f50012b> in <module>()
      1 # Creates the snake
----> 2 snake = snake.Snake( image, closed = True )

~\cakalang\snake.py in __init__(self, image, closed)
     49 
     50         # Image properties
---> 51         self.width = image.shape[1]
     52         self.height = image.shape[0]
     53 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

How to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: How you are executing your `main.py` script?

Comment: That means the image you are passing is a `None`. You should check how is this image created, for example, if you load it, check that is loaded correctly.

Comment: at anaconda prompt
e:\user\user\cakalang>python main.py example.jpg

Comment: my bad. the example.jpg is damaged. I download again and save it correctly. It works. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the traceback, It shows that the `image` you are passing to create `Snake` object is `None`. Please pass proper image frame.

And there is no problem with the object creation. `self` is not an argument it's the part of the Class declaration. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self),